# How can I create a DateTime value in a Linq Query?

Tags: vb.net, linq, entity-framework

I am trying to create a query in Linq to Entities. I want it to return objects that include a DateTime property derived from strings in the table I am querying. The data (in SQL Server) has a string date field (in the database it appears as VARCHAR(8)) called date_occurred. It has a String time field (varchar(6)) called time_occurred.

An example of the contents of date_occurred is "20131007" to represent Oct. 7, 2013. An example of the contents of time_occurred is "145710" to mean 10 seconds after 2:57pm.

I have tried two methods that don't work:

```
Dim ATQuery = From e In EntityContext.vwSecAppAuditToday
   Order By e.date_occurred, e.time_occurred
   Select New AuditEntry With {
      .EventTime = DateTime.ParseExact(Trim(e.date_occurred) & Trim(e.time_occurred), "yyyyMMddHHmmss", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture),
      .ServerName = e.server_name
}
```

This throws a `NotSupportedException` with a message stating: "LINQ to Entities does not recognize the method 'System.DateTime ParseExact(System.String, System.String, System.IFormatProvider)' method, and this method cannot be translated into a store expression."

Before that, I tried:

```
Dim ATQuery = From e In EntityContext.vwSecAppAuditToday
   Order By e.date_occurred, e.time_occurred
   Select New AuditEntry With {
      .EventTime = New DateTime(Integer.Parse(e.date_occurred.Substring(0, 4)),
         Integer.Parse(e.date_occurred.Substring(4, 2)),
         Integer.Parse(e.date_occurred.Substring(6, 2)),
         Integer.Parse(e.time_occurred.Substring(0, 2)),
         Integer.Parse(e.time_occurred.Substring(2, 2)),
         Integer.Parse(e.time_occurred.Substring(4, 2))),
      .ServerName = e.server_name
}
```

This also throws a `NotSupportedException`. In this case, the message states: "Only parameterless constructors and initializers are supported in LINQ to Entities."

Is what I am trying to do possible using Linq to Entities?

**Edit: Comment Alert**

For those who read this post later, Moho and Matt Johnson have made especially helpful comments. I have marked these with +1.

Comment: Could you show us the content of `e.date_occured` and `e.time_occured` ?

Comment: What database are you using, and what db type are the columns you are working with?

Comment: @MattJohnson Thanks for your suggestion, also. The underlying data in SQL Server, the fields I described as "strings" are VARCHAR(8) and VARCHAR(6) respectively in the database. I edited the post to clarify.

Comment: Is there some reason you can't use the correct SQL datatypes such as `DATETIME`?

Comment: Actually, even though I'm not free to change the underlying schema, I'm querying it through a view on a linked server, and I can change the view, so perhaps I need to work on coding the view to do the conversion. Good idea!

Comment: That should work.  Be sure to put an index on that view for the translated column.

Comment: Dates stored as varchar == *facepalm*

Comment: I have to agree, @ChrisDunaway. It's familiar, though, for those of us who remember COBOL!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Select an anonymous class that contains the fields of interest (called a projection), then create DateTime struct per item after the IQueryable has been enumerated:

```
Dim ATQuery = From e In EntityContext.vwSecAppAuditToday
   Order By e.date_occurred, e.time_occurred
   Select New With {
      .DateOccurred = e.date_occurred,
      .TimeOccurred = e.time_occurred,
      .ServerName = e.server_name
}

Dim q2 = From e In ATQuery.ToArray()
         Select New AuditEntry With {
             .EventTime = DateTime.ParseExact(Trim(e.DateOccurred) & Trim(e.TimeOccurred), "yyyyMMddHHmmss", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture),
             .ServerName = e.ServerName
}
```

Comment: It works, and I'm delighted--thanks! But why? Is it because the ParseExact call is now in a query of array data instead of Entity Framework?

Comment: Yes - you must remember that when working with an EF DbContext, you're IQueryable expression will be translated into a SQL statement.  The error you were experiencing was due to the EF Linq to Entities query provider not knowing how to translate your `int.Parse` and `DateTime.ParseExact` calls to SQL as those are .NET constructs.  By enumerating the original DB query by calling `.ToArray()`, you query the DB and get the results locally (in memory), and then you can use all .NET language tools at your disposal as you see fit

Comment: I would think `AsEnumerable` would be vastly preferable over `ToArray`?

Answer (score 0):

Your New DateTime contains only integer, so it looks like 20131008011300 (for 2013/10/08 01:13:00)

`/` between date, `:` between time and a `space` between date and time are missed

Comment: Thanks, but I'm still a little confused: I thought the format string I supplied to the ParseExact method accounted for simple string-of-digits format it was parsing. Also, the exception message stated that Linq "does not recognize the method." Does ParseExact not work with format strings that don't include slashes, colons, and space?

Comment: Based on the exception messages, Linq appears to be very selective in the code that can appear in a Linq query.

Comment: this is not a linq query, this is a linq to entities query